# How to center footer block?

Tags: 7, blocks

Using Drupal 7 with custom zen subtheme.  I created a footer block to hold standard copyright information.  But this block is left aligned, how do I center my footer block?

**UPDATE**

Below is the HTML for my footer.  What CSS selector should I use to identify my footer block?

```
<div class="region region-footer">
 <div id="block-block-1" class="block block-block contextual-links-region first last odd">
  <div class="contextual-links-wrapper contextual-links-processed">
   <div class="content"> &copy; Copyright 2011 example.com </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either:

- Add {text-align: center} to your footer region or block.
- You could specify a width for your block and add {margin: 0 auto}.

Comment: See my update.  Which css selector should I use to identify my footer block?

Comment: use either .region-footer .block {} or #block-block-1 {}

Comment: I don't like the idea of using #block-block-1 because on reading the css you have no idea what #block-block-1 is.

Comment: Use /**/ comments.

Answer (score 1):

Select the class for the element containing the footer block; then add the following CSS properties:

```
.class {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 10%;
}
```

(Replace *.class* with the class of the container.)

Comment: OP has posted the HTML structure, can you please explain more with `exact` CSS rule?

Answer (score 0):

just use the footer tag which is part of the default Zen theme to centralise your footer.

```
#footer {
    text-align: center;
}
```